# How to return referece to base class in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a `base` struct which include 2 members of1 and of2.

The `Derived` class derived inherent it,

which has a function to return a reference to member of `Base` class.

I hope `Derived` can be used in the `main` as following:

```
struct Base {
 public:
  std::ofstream of1;
  std::ofstream of2;
};
class Derived : public Base {
 public:
  Base& write_file() {
    return Base;
  }
};

int main (){
  Derived d;
  d.write_file().of1 << "I'm of1" << std::endl;
  d.write_file().of2 << "I'm of2" << std::endl;
}
```

Compiler throws error about `return Base` :

```
type name is not allowed
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: OK! I wish I can use `d.write_file().of1 ` or `d.write_file().of2 `to write file, rather than `d.of1` or `d.of2`. So it seems can't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Base` is a class and it is not an expression that can be returned.

You can get pointer to the current object with the keyword `this`. You can indirect through that pointer to get a reference to the current object. That reference implicitly converts to reference to base. So, correct solution is:

```
Base& write_file() {
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I add those function to `Base`, call it in `derived`, it's OK: https://godbolt.org/z/ytVgTk

Comment: @curlywei If you have `Base::write_file`, then the `Derived::write_file` appears to be entirely redundant.

Comment: Thanks you. Finally, I decide to use *composition* rather than *inherit*. Because adding `write_file` to `class Base` seems contradictory....I'm felt.https://godbolt.org/z/7Dnvsa

Comment: @curlywei Now, you have both a member, and a base. That doesn't make much sense.